# Defining constants of sufficient precision in Fortran

Tags: fortran, precision, gfortran

Let's say I want to define pi. I have a file `pi.f` which does the following:

```
PROGRAM PI_program
DOUBLE PRECISION PI
PI = 3.1415926535897932
print *, pi
END
```

I then compile:

```
fortran -free-form pi.f
```

and run the output:

```
./a.out
```

This returns,

```
3.1415927410125732
```

i.e. close, but not the same as the initially defined number.

This is an issue if I then want to do trigonometric calculations e.g. take the cos(pi/2) - the difference in the answers is of the order 10^9, due to the asymptote.

Is there a way in Fortran to define pi such that the precision is not lost?

Comment: I'd rather use some better duplicate. There are many for sure.

Comment: I think it is good to have a question phrased like yours, bit there is no point writing the answer again.

Comment: Sure - thanks for the help! I did try to search for an answer before writing this question, sorry for the clutter!